# App Submission with annual renewal?

Tags: iphone, ios, submission

I'm looking to submit a new app, but have some general questions on the app submission.

This is a football app. This app includes yearly content so I'd like to charge $.99 per year for the app. So a user downloads it and pays $.99 that will give them access to the content for 1 year then the next year there will be new content in the app (json feeds, etc) so they will need to buy again?

How do I accomplished this type of app submission? I was thinking I had to create a NEW app each year and have the users download a NEW app each year, is this the only way? If so, I will need to address how/when the users can access the information thru the app and not let them go over the year. Should I include the year in the app setup?

I'd like to create one app and require an annual renewal, then I and the users can use the same app and just push down updates?  Would I give the app a general name then or include the year?

Any directions is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I know there is support for subscription-based apps, perhaps you should take a look into that?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using the Subscriptions feature with In App Purchases. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2). You could offer the app for $0.99 and then charge the subscription after a year, or offer the app for free and require the user to buy the one year subscription to use the app.